# Add functionality after state.go (ui-router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I define states this way:

```
 $stateProvider.
        state('LB', 
           { url: '/LB', 
             templateUrl: 'LBTemplates/LunchBox.html', 
             controller: "lunchBoxCtrl" 
        }).
        state('Search', 
           { url: '/Search', 
             templateUrl: 'LBTemplates/Search.html', 
             controller: "searchCtrl" 
        }).
...
```

on html:

```
  <div ui-view></div>
  <div id=1>1<div>
  <div id=2>2<div>
  <div id=3>3<div>
```

after state.go ,I want to change css of  div 1/2/3  depending on the state selected.
If would like to use state.go and not create my own custom function.
is it possible to add some parameter/function to the state function that enable to change the css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a run block, add $state service on the $rootScope:

```
app.run(function($state, $rootScope) { $rootScope.$state = $state; } );
```

in your html:

```
  <div ui-view></div>
  <div ng-class="{ someCssClass: $state.includes('LB') }>1<div>
  <div ng-class="{ someCssClass: $state.includes('Search') }>2<div>
  <div ng-class="{ someOtherCssClass: !$state.includes('Search') }>3<div>
```

This will add the "someCssClass" class to div 1, if the current state is LB or any substate of LB.

Comment: Looks much simpler. Thanks.

Comment: Actually in my case, I can simply inject $state to the top level controller mainApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope,$state) and then use it with its scope inside the controller.html: <li ng-class="tabClass(tab)" ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
                <a ui-sref="{{tab.link}}" ng-click="setSelectedTab(tab)">{{tab.label}}</a>
            </li>  and in conroller:  $scope.tabClass = function (tab) {    
        if ( $state.includes(tab.link)){
            return "active";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in parameters with `$state.go`. Then you can update the view/css from your controller.

```
$state.go('LB', params);
```

You can read more about it at the [ui-router docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

It's a bit ugly. But it will catch the events

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) { 
    if(toState.name == 'LB') {
       //Do something
    }
})
```

Comment: But then, each time I call $state.go('LB') I will need to include the same params. It makes it hard to maintain. Is it possible to add a function/event to  $stateProvider.state that will execute after go.

Comment: Thanks. As a side question. I use the service $stateProvider why is it called $state in the link you provide?

Comment: It's just two different services in the same module. One is for creating states and the other one ($state) is for "...representing states as well as transitioning between them." as the docs states.

Comment: I saw I can also use onEnter function. So for example    state('Search', {
            url: '/Search', templateUrl: 'LBTemplates/Search.html', controller: "searchCtrl", onEnter: function ($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('selectTabChanged','Search');
            }
        })